# End of File Error in File Handling Program

Tags: java, file-io

I am creating a database project in java using file handling. The program is working without compiling error. Following points are not working

1. File is storing only first record. (if program is running again it is overwriting file)
2. I want to display all records but the only first record is displaying with Exeception

Please offer suggestions..

```
import java.io.*;

public class Student implements Serializable
{
    private int roll;                       
    private String name;                    //To store name of Student
    private int[] marks = new int[5];       //To store marks in 5 Subjects
    private double percentage;              //To store percentage
    private char grade;                     //To store grade
    public Student()
    {
        roll = 0;
        name = "";
        for(int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++)
            marks[i] = 0;
        percentage = 0;
        grade = ' ';
    }
    public Student(int roll , String name ,int[] marks)
    {
        setData(roll,name,marks);
    }
    public void setData(int roll , String name ,int[] marks)
    {
        this.roll = roll;
        this.name = name;
        for(int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++)
            this.marks[i] = marks[i];
        cal();
    }
    //Function to calculate Percentage and Grade
    private void cal()
    {
        int sum = 0;
        for(int i = 0 ; i < 5 ;i++)
            sum = sum + marks[i];
        percentage = sum/5;

        if(percentage>85)
            grade = 'A';
        else if(percentage > 70)
            grade = 'B';
        else if (percentage >55)
            grade = 'C';
        else if (percentage > 33)
            grade = 'E';
        else
            grade = 'F';
    }
    public char getGrade() { return grade; }
    public double getPercentage() { return percentage; }
    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        string format = "Roll Number : %4d, Name : -%15s "
                      + "Percentage : %4.1f Grade : %3s";
        return String.format(format, roll, name, percentage, grade);
    }
}
```

second file

```
import java.io.*;

public class FileOperation
{
    public static void writeRecord(ObjectOutputStream  outFile, Student temp) 
        throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException
    {
        outFile.writeObject(temp);
        outFile.flush();
    }

    public static void showAllRecords(ObjectInputStream inFile) 
        throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException
    {
        Student temp = new Student();
        while(inFile.readObject() != null)
        {
            temp = (Student)inFile.readObject();
            System.out.println(temp);
        }
    }
}
```

main file 
(only two options are working)

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Project
{
    static public void main(String[] args)
        throws IOException,ClassNotFoundException
    {
        ObjectInputStream  inFile;
        ObjectOutputStream outFile;

        outFile = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("info.dat"));
        inFile = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("info.dat"));

        Scanner var = new Scanner(System.in) ;
        int roll;
        String name;
        int[] marks = new int[5];
        int chc = 0;

        Student s = new Student();

        while(chc != 6)
        {
            System.out.print("\t\tMENU\n\n");
            System.out.print("1.Add New Record\n");
            System.out.print("2.View All Records\n");
            System.out.print("3.Search a Record (via Roll Number) \n");
            System.out.print("4.Delete a Record (via Roll Number) \n");
            System.out.print("5.Search a Record (via Record Number)\n");
            System.out.print("6.Exit\n");
            System.out.print("Enter your choice : ");
            chc = var.nextInt();

            switch(chc)
            {
            case 1: 
                System.out.print("\nEnter Roll number of Student : ");
                roll = var.nextInt();
                System.out.print("\nEnter Name of Student : ");
                name = var.next();
                System.out.println("\nEnter marks in 5 subjects \n");
                for(int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++)
                {
                    System.out.print("Enter marks in subject " + (i+1) + " ");
                    marks[i] = var.nextInt();
                }
                s.setData(roll , name , marks );
                System.out.println("\n Adding Record to file \n");
                System.out.printf("Record \n " + s);
                System.out.println("\n\n");
                FileOperation.writeRecord(outFile,s);
                System.out.println("Record Added to File\n ");
                break;

            case 2:
                System.out.println("All records in File \n");
                FileOperation.showAllRecords(inFile);
                break;

            default: System.out.println("Wrong choice ");
            }
        }
        outFile.close();
        inFile.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this only a typo or do you refer to different `Student` classes. In one location you refert o `Student` in singular version in another you access `Students` the plural version.

Comment: I corrected the typing errors and paste full program...

Comment: Suggestion: Try to [avoid redundant comments](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1327761) in the sense of Robert C. Martin, like on the getters or stating this is a parameterless default c'tor, i have already removed them from the listing ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your program found a `ClassNotFoundException` and your method only throws an `IOException`.

I would check your import statements to make sure you are bringing in the class for ObjectInputStream

```
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
```

If you want to get rid of unreported exception try:

Try

```
public static void showAllRecords(ObjectInputStream inFile) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException
```